# undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'

Tags: qt, zlib, cups

I'm using Qt Creator 4.11.0-beta2 (4.10.83) in a project.
Wanted to add CUPS for printing abilities.

Added library libcups.a in the projects *.pro file :

LIBS += \ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.a

When linking I get the error.

:-1: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.a(file.o): undefined reference to symbol 'inflateEnd'

Investigations indicate the problem lies in the dependence zlib1g (>=1:1.2.0)
(I have version zlib1g 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1+b1)

Someone (google) has suggested it happens because linker try to use libzip instead of zlib

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are your sure it tries to link zlib at all? Try `LIBS += -lz`

Comment: yes I have tried LIBS += -lz
That does not solve the problem.

My whole Libs += looks like this

#pkg_check_modules(LIBZIP REQUIRED libz)

LIBS += \
-lz \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.a

#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.a \
# Cairo for å skrive grafisk til CUPS.
-lcairo
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/cairo
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/glib-2.0
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/pixman-1
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/freetype2
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/libpng12

As you can see i have tried a lot :)